# How to add a friendly URL for a application page

Tags: application-pages, layouts

How to mask layouts in the URL while accessing an application page.
I tried accessing an application page but i see layouts in the URL. I want to mask layouts and create a friendly URL.

Comment: If you google vanity url sharepoint, it will show you a great product for friendly URLs (I'm not affiliated)

Answer (score 1):

The application pages should be in the _layouts folder (or _admin for application pages for central admin).

You can put pages at friendly urls, but then they should be site pages, which you provision using a "Module" element from Visual Studio. But be aware that then users will be able to modify them using SharePoint designer.

There are methods to achieve this somehow, but you should not do it in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the URL Rewrite module for IIS:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Please keep Microsoft's supportability statement in mind:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415

Specifically they don't support assymetrical rewrites.